# Splitting columns but not all new rows are created

Tags: python, pandas, strsplit

I have a csv that looks like this:

```
    FIPS     display_name               Value
    2013    "Aleutians East, (AK)"      172.9
    2016    "Aleutians West, (AK)"      172.2
```

I want to split a column into 2 columns. I tried this:

```
df['county','state'] = df['display_name'].str.split(', ',expand=True)
```

The output was this:

```
cnty_fips   display_name    Value   (county, state)
2013    "Aleutians East    172.9    "Aleutians East
2016    "Aleutians West    172.2    "Aleutians West
```

Not sure why the second half of the data is erased and not made into a new column.
How can I get two new columns when I split a column where one gives the county and another the state?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that `str.split` returns two columns, but you are trying to assign that value to a single column. The following should produce the desired output.

```
temp = df.display_name.str.split(", ", expand=True)
temp.columns = ["county", "state"]

pd.concat([df.drop("display_name", axis=1), temp], axis=1)

   FIPS  value          county state
0  2013  172.9  Aleutians East  (AK)
1  2016  172.2  Aleutians West  (AK)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you split a column into two separate columns, you need to store them in two separate columns. In your case, your are storing it in columns, but not wrapping it into the dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Fips': [2013,2016], 
                   'display_name': ["Aleutians East, (AK)","Aleutians West, (AK)"],
                   'value': [172.9,172.2]})
df[['county','state']] = df['display_name'].str.split(',',expand=True)
```

Notice that the two columns are wrapped together into the dataframe as `df[['county','state']]`, while you simply wrote it as `df['county','state']`.

The output looks like:

```
   Fips          display_name  value          county  state
0  2013  Aleutians East, (AK)  172.9  Aleutians East   (AK)
1  2016  Aleutians West, (AK)  172.2  Aleutians West   (AK)
```

If you want to delete the original column before separation

```
df = df.drop('display_name',axis=1)
print(df)
   Fips  value          county  state
0  2013  172.9  Aleutians East   (AK)
1  2016  172.2  Aleutians West   (AK)
```